# php function called from a specific URL clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html

### EDIT: Here's the "better" one.

### First Page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="routeME" name="routeME" action="routeME.php" method="post">
<input id="key" name="key" type="hidden">
<input id="funcA" name="funcA" type="button" value="A">
<input id="funcB" name="funcB" type="button" value="B">
<input id="funcC" name="funcC" type="button" value="C">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('form#routeME :button').click(function() {
   $('#key').val($(this).attr('id'));
   $('form#routeME').submit();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Landing Page

```
<?php

$value = $_POST['key'];

if (isset($value)) call_user_func($value);

function funcA(){
    echo 'function A NEW!';
    }
function funcB(){
    echo 'function B NEW!';
    }
function funcC(){
    echo 'function C NEW!';
    }
?>
```

Below is the first posting...

If you have an HTML form and you POST it to a .php page, how can you pick up what the link or class was that was clicked on? I'm trying to run a .php function on the landing page depending on what link was clicked on in a JQuery function on the POSTing page. Here's what I'm doing right now.

### First Page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#funcA").click(function(){
        $('form#routeME').attr({action: "routeME.php"});
        $('#key').val('A');
        $('form#routeME').submit();
    });
    $("#funcB").click(function(){
        $('form#routeME').attr({action: "routeME.php"});
        $('#key').val('B');
        $('form#routeME').submit();

    });
    $("#funcC").click(function(){
        $('form#routeME').attr({action: "routeME.php"});
        $('#key').val('C');
        $('form#routeME').submit();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="routeME" name="routeME" action="routeME.php" method="post">

<input id="key" name="key" type="hidden">

<input id="funcA" name="funcA" type="button" value="A">
<input id="funcB" name="funcB" type="button" value="B">
<input id="funcC" name="funcC" type="button" value="C">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP Landing page

```
<?php

$value = $_POST['key'];
//echo $value;

if (($value=='A')) {
    A();
    } else if (($value=='B')) {
        B();
        }else if (($value=='C')) {
            C();
            }

function A(){
    echo 'function A!';
    }
function B(){
    echo 'function B!';
    }
function C(){
    echo 'function C!';
    }

?>
```

It's doing what I want in a round about way but is there a better way to get what I want??

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function

```
if (isset($value)) call_user_func($value);
```

`call_user_func` Calls the function with the name passed by `$value`, so if you submitted 'A', your script would run the `A()` function.

EDIT: If you happen to know what "range" of functions to call, you could do a check I've commonly used.

```
if (isset($value))
{
    $array = array('function_1', 'function_2', 'function_3');
    if (in_array($value, $array))
    {
        /* The $value is expected, so try to run the function */
        call_user_func($value);
    }
    else die("Invalid function passed!");
}
```

Comment: But what if the $value and the function name were different?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If, say, you submitted 'register_user' from your form, PHP would search for `registered_user()` and call it, or return `FALSE` if it encountered an error.

Comment: This would allow any user to execute any function. I doubt, for instance, that you *want* arbitrary users to be able to run `phpinfo`...

Comment: "This" what do you mean? How would they run phpinfo from this?

Comment: Disregard my first question. I would be silly to make the $values different anyway.

Comment: @lonesomeday is correct, if one of your users used a tool (FireBug in example) to change the value before the form submit, they can run almost any native (or known user-set) function. I have edited my answer in response.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your JavaScript down to one function:

```
$('form#routeME input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    $('#key').val($(this).val());
    $('form#routeME').submit();
});
```

And then you could employ the Command Pattern on the PHP side to execute functions similar to how you are now, or combine this with DFranks' answer.

Comment: Quick compression! Correct me if I'm mistaken, but @Monty uses input-type-buttons, so instead of `button`, wouldn't you use `input[type="button"]`?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very easy to do this, and doesn't involve any Javascript at all.

If you have an `input type="submit"` element with a `name` and `value` set, that name and value will be set if and only if the button is clicked. Non-clicked buttons will not have their names sent.  So you can see which one is present, and so tell which button was pressed:

```html
<input id="funcA" name="func" type="submit" value="A">
<input id="funcB" name="func" type="submit" value="B">
<input id="funcC" name="func" type="submit" value="C">
<!-- note that type="submit" on all these elements -->
```

Now you can test this very easily in PHP:

```php
if ($_POST['func'] === 'A') {
    A();
} elseif($_POST['func'] === 'B') {
    B();
} elseif($_POST['func'] === 'C') {
    C();
}
```

Note that you don't need any Javascript at all to do this.

Comment: I believe you were aiming for `$_POST['func']` over `$_POST['funcA']` ;)